# Error when trying to remove lines using regex and write to new file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file where each line starts with a '0', followed by a tab, and then ideally some text - however, some lines just have a '0' followed by whitespace, and I need to remove those.

EDIT: I added 'w' to the second file path, as recommended below, but now I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ed7474583899> in <module>
      3     with open('test_02.txt', 'w', ) as append_file:
      4         for line in file:
----> 5             if not pattern(line):
      6                 append_file.write(" "+r)
      7         append_file.write("\n")

TypeError: 're.Pattern' object is not callable
```

when I run this code

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("^0\s+$")
with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    with open('test_02.txt') as append_file:
        for line in file:
            if not pattern(line):
                append_file.write(" "+r)
        append_file.write("\n")
```

but when I run it I get the following error message

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-41d28ce0cbdf> in <module>
      3 pattern = re.compile("^0\s+$")
      4 with open('test.txt') as file:
----> 5     with open('test_02.txt') as append_file:
      6         for line in file:
      7             if not pattern(line):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_02.txt'
```

I've used the same 'with open' command before to remove stop words from the text and save them to a new file, so I'm not sure why it's generating that error now, and I haven't had any luck troubleshooting.

Comment: You should open the new file in writing mode  `with open('test_02.txt', 'w') as append_file:`

Comment: When you leave out the mode argument, it defaults to reading, and of course that fails if the file doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

1. open the file as writeable if you plan to write to that file: `with open( 'name', 'w') as fout` etc.
2. you cannot call compiled `re` pattern `pattern(line)`, you have to use `pattern.match(line)` or something like that.
3. when creating `re` pattern, it's usually a good idea to use `r'...'` string as a pattern.
4. `append_file.write(" "+r)` is an error, since `r` is not defined anywhere.